# Python отрисовка графика функции, считывание tsv файла

Tags: python, matplotlib

Доброго времени суток.

У меня есть задание
[image: Задание]

[image: Вриант]

Я написал код, для отрисовки графика, но у меня возникает ошибка, с которой я не могу справиться, подскажите решение, пожалуйста.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
import numpy
import csv

data = []
with open("test.tsv") as tsvfile:
    tsvreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter="\t")
    for row in tsvreader:
        data = " ".join([int(i) for i in row])

x = numpy.arange(-10.0, 10.0, 0.01)
y = numpy.tan(data[0]*x**2 + data[1]*x + data[3])

matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel(r'Ось OX', color = 'r')
matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel(r'Ось OY', color = 'b')
matplotlib.pyplot.title(r'$y = tg (ax^2 + bx + c)' , color = 'g')
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(x, y, 'r')

matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

[image: Ошибка]
P.S. Может это делается как-то по другому. Я как 2 дня только разбираюсь в Python.

Comment: в ошибке же все написано. вы соединяете в строку числовые значения. во-первых, это не правильно, во-вторых, вам это не нужно. прочитайте про метод списков append.

Comment: вы так же можете приложить к вопросу часть исходных данных в воспроизводимом формате.

Answer (score 0):

Замените

```
for row in tsvreader:
    data = " ".join([int(i) for i in row])
```

на

```
for row in tsvreader:
     for i in row:
         data.append(int(i))
```

За одно разберитесь, в чем отличие join() от append()